# Is there a way to trigger a Google Cloud Function with a Google Datastore event?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-functions

It seems like you can get events from Google Cloud Platform, but not from Google App Engine services. Why is that?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloud Functions is a new service on GCP, whereas Cloud Datastore is a high query per second (QPS) service that is more sensitive to latency changes.

This means it's still early and integration with Cloud Datastore is more complex than most other systems. It's been looked into, but nothing to announce yet.

Comment: Is there any update on this? I need to write a cloud function that updates an aggregate value whenever a certain kind of change happens in datastore. I would prefer if my architecture was event driven.

Comment: It was my first search when I look for event distributed distributed architecture using google cloud. and the answer is always NO. Checkout DynamoDB, which offers excellent event streams out of NO-SQL.

Comment: @NikhilAgarwal Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Datastore Callbacks?  They're somewhat analogous to triggers in an RDBMS environment.  For example, you could write callback methods that get invoked every time an entity of a particular Kind is put or deleted.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/callbacks

Comment: If I understand the documentation note correctly, this seems to be an in-process-only sort of trigger, right?: `Callbacks are not triggered if the App Engine app is called by some other app`.  If that is a correct interpretation, I'm assuming there's no way to use this to track changes to Datastore entities.  Any chance anyone has solved the issue for tracking changes so that one could subscribe to those changes since a point in time?