# Create/update in datastore triggers Cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-functions, datastore

I have a database in Google Datastore. I don't know how to use cloud functions, but i want to trigger an event after a creation or an update.
Unfortunately the documentation is light on the subject : https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/callbacks

I don't know how i could use @PostPut to trigger an event as soon as a line is created or updated.

Does anyone have a tutorial which a basic example ?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dan MacGrath provided an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42804507/is-there-a-way-to-trigger-a-google-cloud-function-with-a-google-datastore-event) to a similar request (callbacks are indeed discussed below. Such solution doesn't exist yet. As a workaround, taking into account the [current available triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/events-triggers):

1. HTTP—invoke functions directly via HTTP requests.
2. Cloud Storage
3. Cloud Pub/Sub
4. Firebase (DB, Storage, Analytics, Auth)
5. Stackdriver Logging—forward log entries to a Pub/Sub topic by creating a sink. You can then trigger the function.

I would suggest a couple of solutions:

1. Saving something in a specific bucket from Cloud Storage every time that a line is created or updated to trigger a linked Cloud Function. You can delete the bucket contents afterwards.
2. Create logs with the same name and then [forward them to Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2#dest-create), by creating a sink.

**EDIT 1**

- Cloud Storage triggers for Cloud Functions: [Official Google doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#event_types) and tutorial with a sample code in `node.js 6` in [Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/functions/helloworld).
- Cloud Pub/Sub triggers for Cloud Functions: [Official Google doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub#event_structure) and tutorial with a sample code in `node.js 6` in [Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/functions/helloworld) (the same than before).

Comment: thanks @Rubén C.   Is there any tutorial to show an example ? thank you

Comment: You are welcome. Check the edit on my answer. I didn't find more specific tutorials but the code samples are quite easy to follow.

Answer (score 3):

Cloud Datastore does not support real-time triggers on CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) events.

However, you can migrate to [Cloud Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/) which does support real-time triggers for those actions (by way of Cloud Pub/Sub which can be made to invoke a Cloud Function). Cloud Firestore is the successor to Cloud Datastore and may eventually supplant it at some point in future.